# Nginx proxying TCP Socket Connections is altering original IP

Tags: nginx, tcp, proxy, nginx-config, tcpsocket

I am using the current configuration and running it as root:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


stream {

    upstream web {
        server 127.0.0.1:8445;
    }

    upstream tcpsocket {
        server 127.0.0.1:8444;
    }

    map $ssl_preread_alpn_protocols $upstream {
        "" tcpsocket;
        default web;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass $upstream;
        ssl_preread on;
    }
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {

        listen 8445 ssl;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;

        ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/cert.key;
        ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/cert.crt;

        ssl_protocols  TLSv1.2;

        location / {

          proxy_set_header        Host $host;
          proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

          # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
          proxy_pass          http://localhost:8443;
          proxy_read_timeout  90;

          proxy_redirect      http://localhost:8443 https://127.0.0.1;
        }

    }
}
```

With a requirement to have only one port open (443), I am trying to:

1. Dispatching http requests to 127.0.0.1:8443 eventually after handling ssl
2. All "other" requests (I only expect tcp socket connections) to a tcp socket server running at 127.0.0.1:8444

This configuration is working perfectly except that the caller IP changes to 127.0.0.1 for tcp connections.
I don't care about the http caller IP.

I tried the following solutions:

```
    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass $upstream;
        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_bind $remote_addr:$remote_port transparent;
    }
```

This causes **upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while proxying connection**

```
    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass $upstream;
        ssl_preread on;
        set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/8;
        real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
        real_ip_recursive on;
    }
```

real_ip settings do not work inside the stream block

```
    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass $upstream;
        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_protocol on;
    }
```

This causes nginx to fail with error **broken header while reading PROXY protocol**

Please help!